# What is the best way to fasten securely a load onto a hollow brick?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, bolting, fasteners, waterproofing

Due to the ongoing COVID pandemic, I decided to put a basketball hoop on one of our outside walls, so that me and my son can stretch a bit. The problem is that the wall I plan to put the basketball is built with hollow bricks, (see below).

[image]

[image]

The thickness of the brick is close to 10cm.
Additionnal specs :

- the wall is getting its fair share or rain during autumn and winter and its facing the wind, so I want to make sure that no moisture will find its way in.
- there may be some dunking (we are on average 100 kg each) involved so I need to make this as robust as possible.

I considered but I find them lacking :

- screw plastic wall plugs

[image]

- screw anchors

[image]

- Toggle Bolts

[image]

- expansion anchors

[image]

- hollow wall anchors

[image]

In most of the cases my main worry is that because the brick is hollow the won't find enough support. So, I wonder what is the best practice for this type of brick.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend first making a hole to fill the channels in the brick with mortar/concrete locally. This way you will effectively have a solid brick which allows for a much stronger fastening and a much larger range of applicable anchors.

The anchors you show above are all mechanical anchors, which is not the optimal solution when a waterproof result is required. You could consider using a chemical anchor in the form of a threaded rod installed with an appropriate resin. (This will require filling the channels of the brick.)